# PHP static variables and old data

Tags: php, static, static-methods

I work on a project that it was started by an other developer. The project has a helper class that it will take an input and fetch data from some offsite registries.

The class is simple and the only thing that it does is to fetch the data.
My boss asked me to use this helper class to create another interface.

So I did. I got the class, built my interface around it and processed the result. All was ok as long as I given single inputs, for a example "a user". When I put the helper function through a loop everything crumples.

I have to inform you that the function in helper class is a static function, which has a loop to some registries. The return of each registry is written through the registry function to a generic static variable. After each registry is called the static variable is returned to the interface.

The result is that on some iterations of the loop I get wrong data, and more specifically I get the previous user`s data.

If for each iteration I preset the static variable to "[]" everything works as expected.

**For example:**

```
class Helper {
    private static $results = [];

    public static askRegistries ($userId) {
        $registries = ['registry1','registry2','registry3'];

        foreach($registries as $registry) {
            self::callRegistry($userId, $registry);
        }

        return self::$results;
    }

    private static callRegistry($userId, $registry) {
        self::$results[] = getData($userId)
    }
}
```

With the above example I am trying to explain to you how the data are set to the static variable and returned to the interface.

**Question #1**

> Is it normal for each call of this static function the static variable
>   to retain the old data?

**Question #2**

> If it is normal, can you explain to me why?

**Question #3**

> Again if it is normal, what is the proper way to solve this problem
>   without making any major changes to the code, as it is prohibited by
>   my boss?

**Edit #1**

**Question #4**
If I change the call to static method **callRegistry** to a registry class that appends to the static variable is there anything else I should keep in mind?

**for example**

```
class Helper {
    public static $results = [];

    public static askRegistries ($userId) {
        $registries = ['Registry1','Registry2','Registry3'];

        foreach($registries as $registry) {
            $registryClass = new {$registry}();
            $registryClass->query($userId);
        }

        return self::$results;
    }
}

class Registry1{   
    public query($userId) {
        Helper::results = doSomething();
    }
}
```

In this example the static variable is public.

Comment: I think it is a normal behavior as static variables are means to retain state. https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-static-variables/

Comment: who is `getData` and why do you even need `registry` in `callRegistry`?

Comment: @Edwin it is an example to show the logic that was used to return the data from the helper class to the interface. it has no real meaning anything that it was written.

Comment: @hanishsingla I will have a look to the link that you gave me as I have to make a report about this to my supervisor.

Comment: an interface can't hold any data, what do you mean?

Comment: @Edwin I mean that I have an interface that collects the data form the helper and returns them to the interface`s caller in the form of the array. The only thing that the interface is doing, is to call the helper and return the collection.

Comment: @Edwin With the above example I want to show you how the previous developer set the static variable and returned to who ever was calling the helper function. The original code that I got from the previous developer was using classes for the registries and not a dummy function "callRegistry". But I can not use that as an example because it is to complicate for a media like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, static functions and static variables belong to Class not class objects.

Above statement concludes that static variables and methods are always meant to call directly from class e.g. MyClass::function() and MyClass::$var

Static variables in a class never meant to handle a state. So you must never change static variables for a class. use Constants instead.

If you want to store data in a variable, just define a normal (private, protected or public) variable in class and then update it through object of class.

If you are calling callRegistry() in a loop, its wise to reset Helper::$results to an empty array as every user you pass in loop is getting added to Helper::$results. which in turn effects your RAM as all this data is stored as a state until your script is ended. 
https://alanstorm.com/php-meminfo-and-memory-leaks/

I think it should solve your issue

```
class Helper {
    private $results = [];

    public static askRegistries ($userId) {
        $registries = ['registry1','registry2','registry3'];

        foreach($registries as $registry) {
            self::callRegistry($userId, $registry);
        }

        return self::$results;
    }

    private callRegistry($userId, $registry) {
        $this->results[] = getData($userId)
    }
}

$helper = new Helper();

foreach($userIds as $userId){
    $helper->callRegistry($userId, $registry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal for each call of this static function the static variable to retain the old data?

And

> If it is normal, can you explain to me why?

It is normal. Static variables are stored within the class, not within a specific instance of the class. Updating a static variable with 1 instance will update it for all instances.

Since the only interaction this helper class has with the static variable is to append to it, it will build and build and build this static variable every time you use it.

> Again if it is normal, what is the proper way to solve this problem without making any major changes to the code, as it is prohibited by my boss?

I personally would change the scope of of the `private` property and method to `protected`.

I would change the behaviour of `callRegistry` to:

1. Assign the response from getData($userId) to a local variable
2. Append this local variable to `self::$results`
3. Return the local variable

I would then write a class to extend `Helper` with a function to overwrite the behaviour of `askRegistries` to return a local array. Like so:

```
// Give the class a real name of course
class ExtendedHelper extends Helper {

    public static function askRegistries ($userId) {
        $output = array();
        $registries = ['registry1','registry2','registry3'];

        foreach($registries as $registry) {
            $output[] = self::callRegistry($userId, $registry);
        }

        return $output;
    }

}
```

You may wish to store `$registries` as a static variable within the parent class as well so you are not re-defining it in the child.